# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest with Apache Spark in SpringBoot with ApplicationRunner

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-spark

I am trying to run `Apache Spark 3.3.2` with `Spring Boot 2.6.6` with `ApplicationRunner` Java 17 Mac OS; I have set this in the `application.properties`: `spring.main.web-application-type=none`

Spring

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication implements ApplicationRunner {

private final MyService myService;

public MyApplication(MyService myService) {
    this.myService = myService;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
    myService.process(args);
}
}
```

Apache Spark session in `MyService`

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
            .master("local[*]")
            .config("spark.ui.enabled", "false")
            .getOrCreate();
```

pom.xml

```xml
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

I get this error when I try to start the Spark Session:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.MetricsServlet.getHandlers(MetricsServlet.scala:51) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.$anonfun$getServletHandlers$2(MetricsSystem.scala:90) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:242) ~[scala-library-2.13.8.jar:?]
    at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.getServletHandlers(MetricsSystem.scala:90) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:660) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2714) ~[spark-core_2.13-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$2(SparkSession.scala:953) ~[spark-sql_2.13-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:201) ~[scala-library-2.13.8.jar:?]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:947) ~[spark-sql_2.13-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
    at com.boomi.intelligence.MyService.process(MyService.java:48) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.boomi.intelligence.MyApplication.run(MyApplication.java:31) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:760) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:317) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
    at com.boomi.intelligence.MyApplication.main(MyApplication.java:24) ~[classes/:?]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
    at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[?:?]
```

Please advise.

Comment: try adding `javax.servlet` to your pom.xml

Comment: @SanuKhan Thank you. Just adding `javax.servlet` not enough. I still got the same error. I have posted my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the responses. Although, `jakarata.servlet-api` already exists in Apache Spark. It still needed `javax.servlet-api`. Adding just `javax.servlet-api` did not resolve the issue. I was able to resolve this issue by adding these in the pom.xml

```
      <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
         <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
         <version>3.1.0</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr4-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>4.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
       <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
      <version>3.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <artifactId>commons-compiler</artifactId>
       <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
       <version>3.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the class javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet, you need to add it in your pom.xml or equivalent:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: 3.1.0 is an older version, the latest is 4.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

But also before you even fix it, if you use java 17 may be switch to SpringBoot 3.0? Because the versions that you use are older versions